# WPF: Dealing with images

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create the following functionality: I want to be able to show an image on a window, if it is provided, or a linear gradient brush if the image is not present. I came up with two approaches:

1. To create a `Border` and to apply `ImageBrush` to the border `Background` property if 
   the image `Uri` is provided, or `LinearGradientBrush` if not. This is easy to 
   implement: The view model would supply the border background property either with image 
   brush or linear gradient brush. But there's one big problem: if the image dimensions 
   don't fit the border size, the image is deformed which is something I wish to avoid. Is 
   there a way to set `ImageBrush` and to preserve the image dimensions ratio, i.e. to 
   apply something like `Stretch = Stretch.Uniform`?
2. To create a `Border` and an `Image` inside of it. Then, to create a data trigger for 
   the border, and if the image `Uri` (a property from the view model) is `null`, to set 
   the `Background` of the border to `LinearGradientBrush` and to leave it blank if
   otherwise. I tried creating this, but the data trigger never understood the `null` 
   case. There is also a problem with the `Image` because if `null` is provided for 
   `ImageSource` property, an exception is thrown. The code looks like this:

   ```
   <Border Width="130" Height="170">
     <Border.Style>
       <Style TargetType="Border">
         <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
             <Setter Property="Background">
               <Setter.Value>
                 <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                   <GradientStop Color="#696969" Offset="0.0" />
                   <GradientStop Color="#2E2E2E" Offset="1.0" />
                 </LinearGradientBrush>
               </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </Border.Style>
     <Image Name="image" Stretch="Uniform">
       <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage 
             DecodePixelWidth="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=Width}" 
             UriSource="{Binding Path=Image}" />
       </Image.Source>
     </Image>
   </Border>
   ```

What is the best and the easiest way to implement such functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageBrush` is derived from the `TileBrush` class, which has a `Stretch` property. So you can use not something like `Stretch = Stretch.Uniform`, but exactly that.

Comment: Ha, it appears I've missed it in the Properties list (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx). Thanks Denis!